# Why my foreach loop not failing even if the Path is wrong

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

i have just created the ssis package. Foreach loop has the source as expression and i wanted it to fail when i provide wrong source path. Instead it succeeds. I have not found any explanation on this anywhere else. Is it not supposed to fail while validating? Any word on this will be helping me understand.

Thanks,
L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Info

The Foreach Enumerators do not fail if there are no objects to enumerate. It's a design decision the team took. Imagine how much more work you'd have to do in every package to handle No *EnumeratorType* Found error.

The downside to this choice, as you've discovered, is that an invalid path will not result in an exception. You will also encounter the same situation if no files matching the `FileSpec` are found as well as if permissions prevent the account from accessing the directory/files.

However, if you look at the execution, SSIS *tells* you that it didn't find anything. As a coworker said, "Warnings are just errors that haven't grown up".

The warning in 2008, would look something like

> Warning: 0x8001C004 at Foreach Loop Container: The For Each File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty.

In 2012, it's a little more elaborate coming from the SSISDB `catalog.operation_messages` table but still conveys that it found nothing.

> FELC Process files:Warning: The For Each File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty.

### Action

If you don't like this behaviour, there are different approaches you can take to resolve it.

The first is to treat the warnings as errors. This is a parameter to [dtexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx) of `/W` or `/WarnAsError` if you're not into the whole brevity thing. That's going to treat **all** warnings as errors though so if your data flow has unused columns but files are found, your package will still fail validation. I like this approach myself as I don't want Warnings when my packages are running unattended. Your tolerance my vary. Additionally, this is a non-standard parameter to running an SSIS package and a less-knowledgeable coworker might omit the parameter in the job creation step and your packages will not blow up.

The second is to handle it yourself. Two immediate implementations would be to have a Script Task after your ForEach Enumerator that returns `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure` This script task is Disabled/Enabled by a Variable which is set to True inside the ForEach enumerator. If the inside of the ForEach is never hit, our Variable is never set to True and therefore the Disabled property on the Script Task outside the container remains False so things blow up.

The other thought would be to add an OnWarning event handler to the ForEach enumerator. You'd then need to parse the `ErrorCode`/`ErrorDescription` System Variables for the appropriate value. It appears, the ErrorCode is `-2147368956` while the Description is `The For Each File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty.\r\n`

Again, once you find those warnings, you'd need to add code to blow up execution. A script task that sets the return value to DTSExecResult.Failure is generally the cleanest mechanism.